# Get jsondiffpatch without oldvalues

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-patch

Im using [jsondiffpatch.net](https://github.com/wbish/jsondiffpatch.net) to create a patch to keep track of differences between two json objects. I do not require using the reverse and unpatch methods which makes use of the "oldValue" in the patches generated.

Is there a way to display only new values in the patch generated?

Comment: A JSON Patch delta format gives you an array of old & new values only in simple cases. More complex cases, like array modifications, or long strings modifications, are represented in a more complex way. Would you only like to take care of the simple cases?